# 'Has all the horses'

Tags: sentence-meaning

In The Godfather by M. Puso I come across the phrase 'all the horses'. Apparently, the horses themselves doesn't meantion there. The context is the following:

> Sonny made a violent gesture. "I know I'm not the man he was. But I'll
>   tell you this and he'll tell you too. When it comes to real action I
>   can operate as good as anybody, short-range. Sollozzo knows that ad so
>   do Clemenza and Tessio, I 'made my bones' when I was nineteen, the
>   last time the Family had a war, and I was a big help to the old man.
>   So I'm not worried now. And our family ***has all the horses*** in a
>   deal like this.

Could you explain the meaning of the entire sentence?

Comment: Maybe it's been used to mean horsepower i.e. effective strength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And our family has all the horses in a deal like this.

It's clear from the context what he means:

> And our family has all the **advantages** in a deal like this.

But the origin of the expression is unclear to me.

The speaker may allude to a horse race in which all the participating horses belong to one owner, meaning he will benefit regarless of which horse comes first.

Or he may allude to the process of [horsetrading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_trading), often used idiomatically to refer to negotiations fraught with difficulties and deceit.

Or he may mean it in the military sense: in the old days, the side having more horses, that is, a more powerful [cavalry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalry), was at an advantage. Imagine the advantage achieved by the side that has *all* the horses (meaning, the other side has none).